# Futures and Forward prices under the Heston model and their spread

Tags: volatility, interest-rates, futures, forward

This might seem like a very trivial question but I am really not so sure about it so I thought I post it here.

Assuming a Heston model of the form
\begin{eqnarray}
dS &=& (r-q)Sdt + \sqrt{v}SdW_{1,t}\\
dv &=& \kappa(\theta - v)dt + \sigma\sqrt{v}dW_{2,t}\\
d\langle W_{1,t}, W_{2,t} \rangle &=& \rho dt
\end{eqnarray}

I can't find a real concise proof or disproof to the following statements:

1. The Futures and the Forward price on $S$ are equal (this one I believe so that's okay)
2. The Futures and the Forward price equal $F(t,T) = S_0 e^{(r-q)(T-t)}$

My main issue with the Forward price is that I would need to find the T-Forward measure and so far I have failed to construct that.

I'm interested in this as a side-question in the much larger question: assuming (for example) a Heston-Hull-White model
\begin{eqnarray}
dS &=& (r-q)Sdt + \sqrt{v}SdW_{1,t}\\
dv &=& \kappa(\theta - v)dt + \sigma\sqrt{v}dW_{2,t}\\
dr &=& \mu(\lambda - r)dt + \epsilon dW_{3,t}\\
d\langle W_{1,t}, W_{2,t} \rangle &=& \rho_1 dt \\
d\langle W_{1,t}, W_{3,t} \rangle &=& \rho_2 dt \\
d\langle W_{2,t}, W_{3,t} \rangle &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}

I'm primarily interested in how and if the stochastic volatility has an effect on the Forward-Futures spread. In my opinion it most certainly must have - after all, as shown in Shreve or Hunt/Kennedy, the spread depends on the covariance between discount instrument and the asset $S$, I'm not making a lot of progress in deriving that convexity adjustment however since I'm not even fully sure about futures and forward prices - after all, the Heston model does not really have closed-form solutions, let alone a "known, parametric" distribution to which one could derive moments. On the other hand I believe that must be possible.

Are there any good pointers on this?

Comment: The forward price is easily proven through simple arbitrage under any model, and is equal to your formula where r= the known fixed rate from t to T.     The futures price is harder to calculate, but the principle is that it must be a martingale in the money market measure (otherwise you have non zero expected daily profit ).